# How to implement while loop into selenium test c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a piece of code which goes onto a website searches for an item then selects the size of the item and adds it to the bag.

Once the item is added to the bag I want to introduce a while loop so it keeps increasing the quantity of the item until it equals or exceeds £200. I understand the while loop will be the best method for this as there isn't a set amount of loops I know I want to do.

I believe the loop should be introduced once one item has been added to the bag as only at this point i'm able to say the quantity of the item. In my loop how can i get my code to verify the price of the quantity of items each time it increments by +1.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Exercise3
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();




            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("nike trainers");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("article img")));


            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();


            IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10.5 - EU 45.5 - US 11.5");


            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']")).Click();

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']")).Click();


    // I believe the while loop should be implemented here
            int number = 200;
            while (number > 200)

            webDriver.Quit();
        }

        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }




    }

}
```

Comment: `I understand the while loop will be the best method for this as there isn't a set amount of loops I know I want to do.` when will it stop?

Comment: It will stop once the amount equals or exceeds £200

Comment: Do you know how to get the value of the cart? In that case you could do `while( (get cart total) < 200)`

Comment: No, How would I verify the value of the bag each time a quantity is added

Comment: Try to read the value of the label that holds the total price on the website and convert it to an int (as it will likely be a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your scenario without using the loops(for /while loop). I have added the logic below. Some element rendering is taking more time. So, I would suggest to add the explicit condition wherever required.

Please find the updated code and refer all the comments for more details

**Main Method:**

```
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("nike trainers");
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();

            //Search Result rendering will take some times.So, Explicit wait is mandatory
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("article img")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();

            IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10 - EU 45 - US 11");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']")).Click();

            //Add to cart takes some time.So, the below condition is needed 
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//span[text()='Added']")));

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']")).Click();
            //Wait condition is needed after the page load
            //wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TitleContains("Shopping"));

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]")));
            //Extract the price from the cart
            string totalPrice =webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;
            //Extract the price amount by exluding the currency
            double pricePerItem = Convert.ToDouble(totalPrice.Substring(1));

            // Just hardcoded the expected price limit value
            int priceLimit = 200;

            double noOfQuantity = priceLimit / pricePerItem;

            IWebElement qty =webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));
            //Quantity values are rounded off with nearest lowest value . Example, 5.55 will be considered as 5 quantity
            SelectElementFromDropDown(qty, Math.Floor(noOfQuantity).ToString());

            //After updating the quantity, update  button will be displayed dynamically.So, wait is added and then update action is performed
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")).Click();
```

**Alternate Approach using Loop:**

I would strongly recommend to use the above approach. since, quantity will be increased one by one for each time until the price limit exceeds the 200

```
        //Extract the price from the cart
        string totalPrice = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;
        double currentTotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(totalPrice.Substring(1));
        double itemPerPrice = currentTotalPrice;

        // Just hardcoded the expected price limit value
        int priceLimit = 200;
        int quantity = 1;

        while(currentTotalPrice < priceLimit && priceLimit-currentTotalPrice > itemPerPrice)
        {
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]")));
            IWebElement qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));
            //Quantity values are rounded off with nearest lowest value . Example, 5.55 will be considered as 5 quantity
            SelectElementFromDropDown(qty, (++quantity).ToString());
            //After updating the quantity, update  button will be displayed dynamically.So, wait is added and then update action is performed
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")));
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='bag-item-edit-update']")).Click();

            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")));
            var temp = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-subtotal-price']")).Text;

            currentTotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(temp.Substring(1));
            Console.WriteLine("Current Price :" + currentTotalPrice);
        }
```

Comment: How can I change the pricelimit so that it only adds until it equals or exceeds £200

Comment: Can you try with the above piece of code and share me the logs, If it is any. I have tested the above code and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @J.dockster: Here, I have hard coded the priceLimit value as 200 and I am calculating the no of Quantity dynamically as double noOfQuantity = priceLimit / pricePerItem;(For Example, If the single quantity price is £30 and expected priceLimit is £200, then no of Quantity will be =200/30 =6.66.After rounding of, value 6 will be considered as no Of quantity),Finally, we can directly select the quantity value based on the above noOf Quantity.

Comment: Ok, but if I want to keep adding till I reach more than £200 would that be possible?

Comment: Can I possibly do a Boolean do that int priceLimit > 200?

Comment: @J.dockster: you can still increase the quantity one by one and I have updated the answer with an alternative way

Answer (score 0):

```
Store the value of the item in a variable before starting the loop and creata a variable with initial value int i =1 and with every time loop runs increment the value by and multiply it by the original value and match is with the value with you fetch from the UI eveytime..
int i = 1
while(condition){
i++
//price for each iteration `enter code here`
i*price for 1 item = "value from the UI"
}
```

Comment: Where would the value be getting stored? and how can i fetch the value from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be added in the place where you have commented `// I believe the while loop should be implemented here`

```
String price = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-item-price bag-item-price--current']"))
            .getAttribute("innerHTML");
int pricePerUnit = (int) Double.Parse(price.substring(1, price.Length - 1));
int qty = 1;
while (pricePerUnit * qty <= 200) {
    qty++;
}
qty--;
IWebElement quantityDropDown = webDriver.FindElement(
        By.XPath("//select[@class='bag-item-quantity bag-item-selector select2-hidden-accessible']"));
SelectElementFromDropDown(quantityDropDown, qty.ToString());
```

Comment: I've got 2 exceptions for price.Length and Integer.toString(qty));

Comment: How can I change my method so it can handle span as that's the next exception i'm getting

Comment: can u tell the line in which you are getting the exception

Comment: I tried to run the code IWebElement Qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='bag-item-price bag-item-price--current']"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Qty, "2"); just to see whether the drop down is working correctly. I get an exception in my selectElementFromDropDown method. Element should have been select but was span

Comment: Qty should be WebElement of Select type not span type