# Exception 'Element should have been select but was div' C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting an exception with a piece of code. My code is adding an item to a bag then I want to select the quantity of the item. When I click on the quantity on the drop down menu to select 2.

My code throws an exception on this line:

```
IWebElement Qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("bagApp"));
SelectElementFromDropDown(Qty, "2");
```

> Element should have been select but was div.

This piece of code is designed to click on the drop down menu.

[image: Screenshot of inspect]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Threading;

namespace Exercise1
{
    class Exercise3
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();


            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.asos.com/men/");
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//input[@data-testid='search-input']")).SendKeys("nike trainers");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[@data-testid='search-button-inline']")).Click();

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            IWebElement country = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("article img")));


            webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("article img")).Click();


            IWebElement Size = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//select[@data-id='sizeSelect']"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Size, "UK 10.5 - EU 45.5 - US 11.5");


            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='text: buttonText']")).Click();

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-testid='bagIcon']")).Click();

            IWebElement Qty = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("bagApp"));
            SelectElementFromDropDown(Qty, "2");

            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-bind='click: update']")).Click();

            //int trainer = 145;

            //while (trainer < 200){
            //    Console.WriteLine(trainer);
            //    trainer = trainer * 2;


            //}

            webDriver.Quit();
        }

        private static void SelectElementFromDropDown(IWebElement ele, string text)
        {
            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);
            select.SelectByText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 36px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-wa11-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-wa11-container" title="2">2</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

Comment: Is this question a continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021904/how-to-implement-while-loop-into-selenium-test-c-sharp/51026469#51026469

Comment: In this line of code `SelectElement select = new SelectElement(ele);` ele should be a Web Element of type Select. By.Id("bagApp") gives a Web Element which is of div type. Hence the exception. Try to get the locator of element which has Select tag before assigning it to Qty.

Comment: Please take a minute to move the HTML from your comment into your question and properly format it. Also reduce the code you have posted to an [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You drop down is made of **Divs** and **spans**, Select class will not help you in this case.

You can try this code :

```
IList<IWebElement> options= webDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("li[class*='select2-results__option']"));  
foreach (IWebElement element in options){  
     if(element.GetText().Equals("2")){  

        element.Click();
    }
    }
```

Note that before trying to select value from drop down , you have to click on down arrow button for that you can use this **code** :

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span#select2-d2bx-container+span")).Click()
```

You should use explicit wait as you are moving to new page for this operation.

Comment: Will this stop the exception from occurring?

Comment: Note that you have to click on down arrow button/span to let your webdriver know that there are element present in. For that you can get the code from my updated answer. Update me with the observation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the webelement as below

```
//Explicit wait is added to ensure that my bag item section is loaded successfully
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]")));

IWebElement qtyElement = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[contains(@class,'bag-item-quantity')]"));
SelectElementFromDropDown(qtyElement,"2");
```

Comment: I'm now getting no such element exception. Don't think bag-item-quantity is valid

Comment: Can you try this `IWebElement quantityDropDown = webDriver.FindElement(
        By.XPath("//select[@class='bag-item-quantity bag-item-selector select2-hidden-accessible']"));`

Comment: Still not able to locate it. You can see this by going to http://www.asos.com/men/ > search Nike trainers> click on first one> select any size and add to bag> go to the bag top right hand corner> change quantity to 2

Comment: I am able to highlight the quanity dropdown in the above site using above both the xpath

Comment: @J.dockster: Please add some wait time before the above condition.Since, It is working fine for me,

Comment: My SelectElementFromDropDown method throws an exception. It was expecting select but was span

Comment: @J.dockster: Actually, the above mentioned XPath is correct and element rendering is taking some time. So, Please add some explicit wait before the above action. I have updated the answer with the explicit wait condition.

Comment: @J.dockster: Please check the updated answer with explicit wait

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because you are using the `SelectElement` class on an HTML element that is not a `SELECT`, a `DIV` in this case.

In order to select the desired option, you need to click the dropdown to open it and then click the desired option from the dropdown. Since you will likely be selecting options more than once, it's a good idea to put the code to do that into a function.

```
public void SelectOption(string s)
{
    new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector($"span[title='{s}']"))).Click();
}
```

Then call it like

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.select2")).Click();
SelectOption("2");
```